# Kafka Connect - how to send and handle nested JSON?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect

I have a message, that works with my Redis Sink Connector (connector puts value to Redis):

```
    {
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "registertime"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "userid"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "regionid"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "after"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false,
    "name": "ksql.users"
  },
  "payload": {
    "registertime": 1493819497170,
    "userid": "User_1",
    "regionid": "Region_5",
    "after": "MALE"
  }
}
```

but I want to have the field "after" as nested object:

```
    "after": {
        "one": null,
        "two": "one"
    }
```

and based on that, work with data (i.e. if "one" is null, skip).

so I have a connector:

```
{
    "name": "connector1",
    "config": {
        "topics": "topic1",
        "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connect.redis.error.policy": "NOOP",
        "connect.redis.host": "localhost",
        "connect.redis.port": "6379",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "connect.redis.kcql": "INSERT INTO prod- SELECT * FROM topic1 PK after;"
    }
}
```

and I want to extract the data from the nested json in messsage.
my command to proudce the message:

```
topc=topic1
message=message.json
echo "key:$(jq -rc . $message)" | $kafka_dir/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic $topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:"
```

How can I send a nested json object and how can I extract just one field from it via Transforms, and based on it's value process or not?

Answer (score 0):

Sending nested data works the same as a regular message.

You should be able to update the message to contain something like this schema information for the after field

```
"type": "struct", 
"fields": [{"field": "one", "optional": false, "type":"string"},... ], 
"optional": false, 
"field": "after"
```

Then update the payload accordingly.

I've personally never used the JSONConverter schema/payload types since Avro is more preferred for such a scenario

---

To my knowledge, Kafka Connect cannot skip messages; it'll process all of them. There is also no builtin transform for extracting arbitrary nested values beyond a depth of one, so getting the fields *within* the `after` Struct may be an issue. However, you might be able to get it with modifying the `SELECT * FROM topic1` KCQL statement for this particular connector

In general, if you need logic like this, you'd use a Stream processor such as KSQL or Kafka Streams to filter/modify the topic before dumping into the database

Comment: Thanks, but AFAIK Kafka Connect can skip messages - via Transforms, for example ExtractField ($Key or $Value) and then Tombstone or Filter ($Key or $Value).

My question is how to send in a payload nested object - instead of string (as I tried to show). What I want to obtain, is to work with Transforms not on the string, but on object {"one": "two", "three": "four"}. How can I send it, to have after ExtractField$Value another object, and then via next Transforms (for example Tombstone or Filter) working on object, not string

Comment: Producing nested data isn't any different from a single line of text, for kafka-console-producer. If you want the after field to be nested, it needs to be a Struct schema type, not `"type": "string"`, with the payload updated according which would be controlled by your producer, not Connect or a transform

Comment: yes and I am asking how to produce such payload, because if I change `string` for `object` in schema, connector shows error that it doesn't understand such type. So my question is, how should such a message (payload) look like

Comment: Did you try something like this? `"type": "struct", "fields": [{"field": "one", "type":"string"},... ], "field": "after"`? Otherwise, I'd suggest you use Avro rather than JSON where you don't need a schema and payload

Comment: ok, so I used `struct` as you suggested, thanks. now I extracting it via SMT:
        "transforms": "ExtractAfter",

        "transforms.ExtractAfter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",

        "transforms.ExtractAfter.field": "after"

        "connect.redis.kcql": "INSERT INTO prod- SELECT one FROM struct6 PK one;"

but this kcql doesn't work:
`The value for the record must be String or Bytes.`
how can I use kcql here to SELECT "one" field from "after" and then INSERT value of "one" ("two")?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: my goal is, to have from after: {"one": "two", "three": "four"} 

key: `prod-two`; value `"four"` in Redis

Comment: I'm not familiar with the KCQL syntax since it's connector specific, but where are you getting something called "struct6"?

Comment: it's just the name of the topic, should be topic1 in this case. But not sure if I should use here SELECT * FROM topic ?

Comment: `SELECT one` or maybe `SELECT * FROM x PK one` seems correct to me, based on https://docs.lenses.io/3.2/connectors/sink/redis.html#kcql-support

Comment: Oh, I have it! I was using connector `com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector` insted of `com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.redis.sink.RedisSinkConnector` so that was a reason of the problem